# On Hover Move The Text Up

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

So I'm trying to move up the text when you hover over the image but I can't seem to get it to work. I tried using :hover and then using padding-bottom to move it up but it didn't work. So I basically want the text "Nature" or "Bengal Tiger" to move up when you hover over the image. Here's a pic that illustrates what I want to achieve.

[image]

**Here's the code**

http://jsfiddle.net/Qf4Ka/10/

**HTML**

```
<section id="top-container" class="top-column" style="width:1050px; height:400px; ">

<div class="image" style="float:left;"><img src="http://www.hdwallpapersinn.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/HD-Wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" border="0"; width="263"; height="200" style="display: block; border-top: 1px solid #dddddd; border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd; border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;">
<h4 style="font-size:30px; top: 90px; ">Nature</h4>
</div>

<div class="image" style="float:left;"><img src="http://www.hdwallpapersart.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/tiger_wallpapers_hd_Bengal_Tiger_hd_wallpaper1.jpg" border="0"; width="262"; height="200" style="display: block; border-top: 1px solid #dddddd; border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd; ">
<h4 style="font-size:30px; top: 90px;">Bengal Tiger</h4>
</div>

</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.image { 
   position: relative; 

}

h4 { 
   position: absolute;    
   width: 100%; 
   color: #fff;
   float: left;   
   position: absolute;      
   font-size: 40px;
   font-family: "Oswald";
   text-align: center;
   max-height:auto;
   z-index:20;
   text-shadow:1px 1px 2px #000;
   -moz-text-shadow:1px 1px 2px #000;
   -ms-text-shadow:1px 1px 2px #000;
   -o-text-shadow:1px 1px 2px #000;
   -webkit-text-shadow:1px 1px 2px #000;

}

.image { 
   position: relative; 

}

.image:before{
content:'';
box-shadow:0 0 50px 4px #000 inset;
-moz-box-shadow:0 0 50px 4px #000 inset;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 50px 6px #000 inset;
float:left;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
z-index:20;
cursor: pointer;

}

.image:hover:before {
    box-shadow:0 0 100px 30px #000 inset;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 100px 30px #000 inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 100px 30px #000 inset;
    transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
}
```

Comment: You should check your css  `position: absolute;    
   float: left;   
   position: absolute;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
.image:hover h4 {
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/Qf4Ka/12/)**

Answer (score 0):

The text is placed absolutely relative to the `div.image` element using `top:90px`. Adding padding at the bottom will not change this, it will only add some padding below the text. You can see this if you add a visible border to the text.

The easiest way to handle this is to change the top position of the text when the mouse hovers the image. See the [udpated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qf4Ka/13/).

NOTE: I've only updated the first image so that you can compare the two elements to see the difference.